# Why is my javascript function return not working?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code:

```
  server.getConnections(function(err, count) {
    console.log(count)
    this.connections = count;
    return connections
  });
    console.log(connections);
```

I get connection is undefined but count has value of 1 actually.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you're assigning to `this.connections`?

Comment: This seems like a mixture of programming basics and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: thank you the comment with the link to async function return was helpful.

Comment: Lye Fish what do you mean im not calling the function? Im calling server.getConnection() and this is the callback function form which I want to return the count?

Comment: You miss a few semicolons .. and shouldn't it be `return this.connections;` ?